# How do I present in a Uml use-case Diagram a toolbar

Tags: uml, use-case-diagram

I am new to object oriented design and I wanted to do my first ever UML use case Diagram on a simple application which contains toolbar on the top left corner. The toolbar is called files and when the **user** clicks on it,a drop down menu is opened with options to open a slide,save slide,make new slide and exit the application.
My question is, am I doing it correct with **Use-Case inheritance(Generalization)** ?
This is my diagram.
[image]

Comment: Nope. That's just nonsense. I recommend to read Bittner/Spence about use cases. There's a lot of rubbish around there in lectures/books (and even the UML specs itself). But these guys are spot on.

Comment: @qwerty_so Thank you for the answer ! I wanted to know, is it going to be better to just create use cases for each functionality ?

Comment: No. Use cases are not about functions but added value.

Comment: to simplify use cases are used to say "what to do" and not "how to do", and a toolbar is part of "how to do", the toolbar is not a goal by itself byt a way to accomplish it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sorry to disapoint you, but I have to tell you that this practice is just plain wrong:

- From the point of view of the **semantics**,  the [use-case specialization](https://sceweb.uhcl.edu/helm/RationalUnifiedProcess/process/modguide/md_ucgen.htm) means that `Open presentation` **is a** special form of `Check file`, and `Save file` as well, and that the actor could use them interchangeably and independently. But this cannot be what you mean:  exiting a presentation is at best a sub-part of checking a file
- From the point of view of the **purpose**, a use-case should represent a user goal.  It's part of the problem space, i.e. what the user wants to achieve.  It's not part of the solution space, i.e. how the user will achieve it.  A toolbar is not a goal: it's a user-interface element.
- From the **engineering practice** perspective, use-case should not be used for user-interface design.  It's not my own statement,  but that of Jacobson, Booch and Rumbaugh, the founding fathers of UML:

  > The problem is that the [use-case] descriptions often contain implicit decisions about user-interfaces. Later, when the user interface designers suggest suitable user-interfaces for the use-case , they may be limited by those decisions.
  > in *The unified software development process*, page 164

So in conclusion, it's a bad idea to start use-cases from the user-interface.  It locks you into your own design and ignores the user experience.  You should focus instead only on the user needs.  THe same use-case could then be used whether you'll implement it using a GUI interface,  a chatbot interface,  or a a voice-based interface.

Answer (score -2):

While drawing Use Case diagram, one thing you should focus on is, the actual meaning of it and the purpose of drawing it.

A Use Case refers to what the users in respect of their type are able to do in your System... Anything inside the boundary is what system is capable of doing or what it can provide as a service to its users.

While naming the use cases, you should only use verbs and actions, for example:

1- Login | 2- Submit a Request | 3- Update Profile Description

You should avoid any nouns in them.

There are several relationships that exist in a Use Case Diagram among use cases, and a relationship among actors and use cases of the system, And They are as follows:

Association: the only relationship that can exist between an actor and a use case; Which says the actor is initiator of this use case, or is the one who is caple of operating the use case.

[image]

***In the example above, User is caple of loggin in and submitting a complaint.***

Include: Use Cases can include one or more use cases. When a use case includes another use case, it means the included use case or use cases happen all the time and are part of the initial use case.

[image]

***Paying fees is included, because user has to pay the fees in signing up process, it has to be done, and it's part of the baseline path of the scenario.***

Extend: When a use case is not happening all the time, and is part of your alternative path ( Alternative path of the complete scnario for this use case ), the use case should be extended to the base use case.

[image]

***Forget password is extended to Login use case, because it doesn't happen all the time, and it's part of a alternative path of Login scenario.***

Generalization: When there exist several different ways that a use case can be performed and completed, we use generalization. The inheritent use cases should all be of the same type as the inherited use case.

[image]

***Submitting a complaint can be done in several different ways, in this case, we need to seprate each use case and inherit from from the submit a complaint use case which includes paying fees, this shows that, paying fees is a part of every type of complaint which is submitted.***

Comment: "Login" is a notoriously bad example for a proper use case. Where is the added value of the login use case for it's actor? Nobody ever came to his computer saying "Ah, lets log in to the website". Submit complaint is a much better one. Also, something that is an alternate path of a use case should not be an extending use case.

Comment: You're right about "Login" use case, it's not a value it self, but it brings the possibility of achieving desired values from the system( Without logging, the system is barely useable at some point). I've researched about and used UML in 2 different projects and have reviewed more than enough number of Use Case Diagrams, anytime we have a process that requires several steps of actions that user will do in rare cases, the process is added to the alternative path of the base scenario, it would be great if you could clarify what you mean... thanks @GeertBellekens

Comment: The base use case doesn't know about the extending use case, so it cannot use that in the "alternate path". In a lot of cases, describing the alternate path is enough, no need to actually create a use case for that "functionality". If you do need that, you can still do that with an include. You can include another use case from an alternate scenario as well; not only from the base scenario.